# Curly brackets / illegal chars in Angular [pattern]

Tags: regex, angular

**`Unexpected token '{'`**

I have a simple RegEx that I'm trying to use to validate a number format, i.e. 1234-1234-12

`[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}`

When I try to add this to my template forms, it breaks the Angular binding because of the curly bracket.

```
<input id="accountNumber" name="accountNumber" [(ngModel)]="entryForm.accountNumber"
     type="text" required [pattern]="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}" />
```

I can reference it as a variable in the controller, but that kind of pollutes the controller.  It feels messy to have an extra variable that's only being used once.

```
<input id="accountNumber" name="accountNumber" [(ngModel)]="entryForm.accountNumber"
     type="text" required [pattern]="accountNumberValidationPattern" />
```

Is there any way to escape the regex in the template?

Comment: Try removing the square brackets around `pattern` if you're going to pass in a regex directly. Like this: `pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you used square brackets around the pattern attribute angular looked for a variable named "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}" and no to a string

```
   <input id="accountNumber" name="accountNumber" [(ngModel)]="entryForm.accountNumber"
     type="text" required pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}" />
```